# PyQt, SQLAlchemy - weird insert crash

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyqt

I'm trying to convert an xml to sqlite and get a weird error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Temp\xxx\scripts\xml_to_db.py", line 212, in <module> 
win = Test(a)
File "C:\Temp\xxx\scripts\xml_to_db.py", line 20, in __init__
self.testdb()
File "C:\Temp\xxx\scripts\xml_to_db.py", line 133, in testdb
row = connection.execute(t_id)
File "C:\Temp\PortablePython\App\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1405, in execute 
params)
File "C:\Temp\PortablePython\App\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1538, in _execute_clause
element
compiled_sql, distilled_params
File "C:\Temp\PortablePython\App\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1646, in _execute_context 
context)
File "C:\Temp\PortablePython\App\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1639, in _execute_context 
context)
File "C:\Temp\PortablePython\App\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 330, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
InterfaceError: (InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. u'SELECT temperatures.id \nFROM temperatures \nWHERE temperatures.temperature = ?' ('50',)
```

where line 130 corresponds to

```
t_id = select([tb_temperatures.c.id], tb_temperatures.c.temperature == temp)
```

Here's the whole code

```
def testdb(self):
    db_file = "C:/Temp/xxx/data/xxx/db.sqlite"

    file=QFile(db_file)
    if file.exists():
        file.remove()

    db = create_engine('sqlite:///' + db_file)
    connection = db.connect()

    metadata = MetaData()

    tb_materials = Table('materials', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('material', String)
        )

    tb_temperatures = Table('temperatures', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('temperature', String)
        )

    tb_mat_data = Table('mat_data', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('mat_id', None, ForeignKey('materials.id', onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE")),
        Column('temp_id', None, ForeignKey('temperatures.id', onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE")),
        Column('density', String),
        Column('elasticity', String),
        Column('stress', String)
        )

    auto_assign(metadata, db)
    metadata.create_all(db)

    for m in ['SS 316']:
        data = tb_materials.insert().values(material = m)
        connection.execute(data)

    for t in ['25', '38', '50', '150']:
        data = tb_temperatures.insert().values(temperature = t)
        connection.execute(data)

    materials = ['SS 316']
    for material in materials:
        m_id = select([tb_materials.c.id], tb_materials.c.material == material)
        row = connection.execute(m_id)
        data = row.fetchone()
        m_id_key = data[0]
        temps = ['25', '38', '50', '150']
        for temp in temps:
            QMessageBox.about(self,"",temp)
            t_id = select([tb_temperatures.c.id], tb_temperatures.c.temperature == temp)
            row = connection.execute(t_id)
            data = row.fetchone()
            t_id_key = data[0]
            z = tb_mat_data.insert().values(mat_id = m_id_key, temp_id = t_id_key)
            connection.execute(z)

    connection.close()
    quit()
```

which crashes at the 3rd value of temp = '50'.

I'm totally puzzled and can't find what's wrong with it.

Comment: So you are saying that the contents of temp.text (which is the string `?'('50',)` according to the error message) is not really the content defined in the XML attribute? In that case it's a problem with XML parser, not with sqlalchemy or sqlite, no?

Comment: There's no problem with the xml parser because, as I said, all temp.text values are shown correctly in the messagebox (if I delete the last line). Furthermore, I use the xml file and same parsing methods in the program - no problem. I just want to change from xml to sqlite.

Comment: Your error says problem in `t_id = select([tb_temperatures.c.id], tb_temperatures.c.temperature == temp.text)` but you are removing the last insert statement and its works? Please provide the whole traceback you got on console.

Comment: yes, because without the last statement the insert is not performed (I could've removed/commented out the last 2 lines) - this means everything works fine without the DB insert, but with the insert it crashes after 2 iterations BUT (!) it does insert the first 2 values in the DB. Here's the trace above.

Comment: What is the type of `temperatures.temperature` field? Please provide the table structure. If you can provide the code to generate the same tables in our system then it will be good.

Comment: Please see full code above. temperatures.temperature is a String.

Comment: Anyone? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in my way. **I dont have QT4 and sqlitefktg4sa for testing** so i convert your code limited to SQLAlchemy syntax only. I also dont have your xml to parse so I inserted dummy values.

code is

```
import sys
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, Float, MetaData, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, and_

db_file = "/my/home/db.sqlite"
db = create_engine('sqlite:///' + db_file, echo=True)
connection = db.connect()

metadata = MetaData()

tb_materials = Table('materials', metadata,
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
            Column('material', String)
            )

tb_temperatures = Table('temperatures', metadata,
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
            Column('temperature', String)
            )

tb_mat_data = Table('mat_data', metadata,
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
            Column('mat_id', None, ForeignKey('materials.id', onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE")),
            Column('temp_id', None, ForeignKey('temperatures.id', onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE")),
            Column('density', String),
            Column('elasticity', String),
            Column('stress', String)
            )


metadata.create_all(db)


matlist = ['mat1', 'mat2', 'mat3']
templist = ['temp1', 'temp2', 'temp3']

data = tb_materials.insert().values(material = "CS")
connection.execute(data)

for m in matlist:
    data = tb_materials.insert().values(material = m)
    connection.execute(data)

for t in templist:
    data = tb_temperatures.insert().values(temperature = t)
    connection.execute(data)


m_id = select([tb_materials.c.id], tb_materials.c.material == 'mat3')
row = connection.execute(m_id)
data = row.fetchone()
m_id_key = data[0]

t_id = select([tb_temperatures.c.id], tb_temperatures.c.temperature == 'temp1')
row = connection.execute(t_id)
data = row.fetchone()
t_id_key = data[0]

z = tb_mat_data.insert().values(mat_id = m_id_key, temp_id = t_id_key, density = 'density', elasticity = 'electricity', stress = 'stress')
connection.execute(z)

connection.close()
```

I tested this in Python 2.7, SQLAlchemy 0.7, Fedora. This is working for me. Please try in your place if its working then please provide the xml data which is creating problem.

Hope this will help you to understand your problem.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the XML, I replaced xml with temps = ['25', '38', '50', '100'] and it still crashes exactly at '50'. WTH! It's insane. Or I am?

Comment: Yes, your code works. So do all mine in other modules. Something's weird with this particular one.